# Ember App Kit: Controller without Route is not recognized?

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

as I mentioned in several questions here I am migrating an already existing and running Ember project to use Ember App Kit and I ran into several problems... here's another "problem" which wasn't a problem before :)

I've got a `NotificationCollectionController` which is placed under `app/controllers/notification/collection.js`.

**file** 'app/controllers/notification/collection.js':

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  addNotification: function (options) {
    // some code
  },
  notifyOnDOMRemove: function (notification) {
    this.removeObject(notification);
  }
});
```

As this is the controller for notifications which are rendered through a named outlet I didn't declare a route for it.

Within my `ApplicationRoute` I want to access this controller within a function

**file:** 'app/routes/application.js'

```
import BaseRoute from 'appkit/routes/base';

export default BaseRoute.extend({
  addGlobalNotificationCollection: function () {
    var controller = this.controllerFor('notificationCollection');
    // some more code...
  }
});
```

But as soon as the application starts and this piece of code gets called I traced down the following error:

> "Assertion Failed: The controller named 'notificationCollection' could
>   not be found. Make sure that this route exists and has already been
>   entered at least once. If you are accessing a controller not
>   associated with a route, make sure the controller class is explicitly
>   defined."

What does it mean and why is it thrown? What do I have to do to **make it run** again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't recognize that the **hint** is already given at the [Naming Conventions](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/naming-conventions.html) section of the [Ember App Kit Webpage](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit):

It says, that the naming convention for a Controller is, for example: `stop-watch.js`

> And if it’s a route controller, we can declare nested/child controllers like such:
>   `app/controllers/test/index.js`

So I placed my `NotifcationCollectionController` in `controllers/notification-collection.js` and call it like `Route#controllerFor('notification-collection')` and everything works as expected :)

Comment: I'm running a similar issue here, how is your Route file looking like? Cheers